# Reason for security software to not scan directories with more than 10,000 resources in them?

Tags: linux, files, directory

We have a security software on Linux which scans for exploits in files that exist in directories on the server (such as if websites had hack scripts uploaded to them).  It defaults to a limit of 10,000 resources per directory or else it won't scan the files in that directory, but it permits setting it to unlimited if desired.

I was thinking of increasing the limit but was wondering if there's something about Linux and lots of files in a directory that causes some sort of non-linear slowdown or some other reason for limiting.  Like would scanning a directory with 50,000 files take exponentially longer than scanning 500 directories of 100 files each or some other reason?

EDIT: here are some benchmarks in response to the comments

```
### directory with 50,000 test files ###

# time for file in *; do echo test > $file; done
real    0m3.432s  
user    0m1.128s 
sys     0m2.303s     

# time for file in *; do  a=$(head -1 $file); done
real    1m1.338s
user    0m5.878s
sys     0m22.885s


### directory with 500 test files ###

# time for i in {1..100}; do ( for file in *; do echo test > $file; done ) ; done 
real    0m4.150s 
user    0m1.309s 
sys     0m2.801s

# time for i in {1..100}; do ( for file in *; do a=$(head -1 $file); done ) ; done
real    0m58.278s
user    0m3.558s
sys     0m18.554s
```

Comment: a single directory with huge number of files is not something you want to have under any operating system. If you have such directories, it means the proper housekeeping is not being done on that server. And yes, when the number of files in the directory reaches critical levels, scanning those files will start to take longer and longer. I can not speak for exponential growth in the mathematical sense but you may say that practically speaking. Try this command on  a directory with 500 files and 10000 files `time ls -l | awk '{print $9}'` and see the results

Comment: @MelBurslan Performance seems comparable.  I created 500 files in a dir using `touch test{1..500}` and 50000 in a dir using the same type of syntax.  I ran `time for i in {1..100}; do ( echo *  > /dev/null ) ; done` in the 500 one and `time echo * > /dev/null` in the 50000 one.  Any issues with my approach or any other thoughts?

Comment: In this approach you are not opening files other than sending everything to /dev/null. Try doing something like `a=$(head -1) $file` and/or `echo test > $file` and see how the performance is

Comment: @MelBurslan I added some benchmarks in the answer in response to your comment.  In one case 50,000 files in a dir is faster and in the other 500 is.

Comment: @MelBurslan, that depends on lots of details, like filesystem, size of files (some filesystems keep small files' contents in the inode), in-memory caching, ... But in general, you are certainly right, filesystems are optimized for smallish directories, as it is the overwhelmingly common use case.

Comment: No way for us to be able to answer *why* they selected that limit (if any).

Comment: @vonbrand I guess I was wondering about general performance principles that might cause anybody to set a limit like that - this was just my particular example.

Comment: Two reasons I can think of for the limit: (1) it sorts the entries alphabetically using a non-logarithmic algorithm (2) it was written for systems that may have long-latency disks (either old computers or iSCSI),  and running `stat()` on more than 10000 files as part of a tree walk was thought to take too long.

Comment: Practically speaking, 10,000 files in a single directory _usually_ means a logging system that's gone a bit bonkers. Quite low priority to virus sweep as a result. But also bear in mind the size of the directory inode chain is directly related to number of entries - this could be a factor.